# Integral Car Traffic Problem for $f(t) = 50*t*sin(\sqrt{t})$

Tags: calculus

So I have a question for this traffic function $f(t) =50t*sin(\sqrt{t})$ where f(t) is the rate at which cars pass through an intersection from noon(t=0) until 5pm (t=5). The question is asking to find any two hour interval where the total # of cars passing through the intersection is between 200 and 300.

I tried doing $\int{f(t)} dt$ with the lower limit being x, and the upper x+2, but then I do not know what to set it equal to: either 200, or 300

Comment: is this not an old ap calculus exam question. i remember doing it in class.

Comment: I am doing ap calc hmwrk...but idk if it is an exam question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to find $x, 0 <  x < 5$ so that $$200 <  \int_x^{x+2} 50 t\sin( \sqrt t) \, dt < 500\to 4 <  \int_x^{x+2} t\sin( \sqrt t) \, dt < 10$$

i checked the $\int_x^{x+2} t\sin( \sqrt t) \, dt $  is increasing on $[0,3]$ and the maximum value is smaller than $10,$ takes $4$ a little after $1.1$

Comment: so like 2 and 4

Comment: @ILikeMath, $x > 1.1$ is all you need.

Comment: the question is asking for a two hour interval though

Comment: @ILikeMath, you can have a two interval like $[1.1, 3.1], [1.5, 3.5], \cdots$ only constraint seems to be the left end point be greater than $1.1$. you can use your ti-83, put this $FnTnt(t\sin \sqrt t, t, x, x+2)$ in $Y1$ andn graph it in window $[0,3]$ by $[0,12]$. you can see much better there.

Comment: ok cool thanks a lot

Comment: @ILikeMath, you are welcome. good luck on your ap exam.